# create discord bot commands from server

Tags: python, discord, bots

i'm new at programming, i'm coding a bot in python and i want my discord friends to be able to create custom commands

e.g:

**user:** !create

**bot:** write the first word that will be the command and the second word or phrase that will be the answer, separated by a comma.

**user:** hello, goodbye

**bot:** command successfully created

**user:** !hello

**bot:** goodbye

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you would have to create global dictionary - ie. `cmds` - and keep values as `cmds["!hello"] = "goodbye"`. And you would have to use `on_message` to check message (`!hello`) in this dictionary and send back value from dictionary (`goodbye`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create global dictionary - ie. `my_commands` - and in `!create` put values as `my_commands["!hello"] = "goodbye"`.

And you need to use `on_message` to check message (`!hello`) in this dictionary and send back value from dictionary (`goodbye`)

```
    # split message into list - so you could send with some arguments (but I don't use it
    cmd, *args = msg.content.split(' ')
    
    if cmd in my_commands:
        answer = my_commands[cmd]
        await msg.reply(answer) 
    else:
        # send to other commands - like `!create`
        await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

---

Minimal working code:

I made simpler version. You have to put all values in one line without `,`

```
!create hello goodbye
```

but this version still has few disadvances:

- you can add own command `create` and it will block original `!create`
- new `hello` will replace existing `hello`
- doesn't test who can add commands

---

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    print("[on_connect] connected as", bot.user.name)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("[on_ready] ready as", bot.user.name)

# global dictionary with example command.
my_commands = {
    '!test': 'Hello World!'
}

@bot.command('create')
async def create(ctx, *args):
    #print('[create] ctx:', ctx)
    #print('[create] args:', args)
    
    if len(args) >= 2:
        key = '!' + args[0]
        val = args[1]
        my_commands[key] = val
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg, *args):
    #print("[on_ready] msg:", msg)
    #print("[on_ready] args:", args)
    
    #print("[on_message] got message as", bot.user.name)
    #print("[on_message] msg.author:", msg.author)
    #print("[on_message] msg.author.bot:", msg.author.bot)
    #print("[on_message] msg.content:", msg.content)

    # skip messages from bots
    if msg.author.bot:
        return

    cmd, *args = msg.content.split(' ')
    
    if cmd in my_commands:
        answer = my_commands[cmd]
        await msg.reply(answer) 
    else:
        # send to other commands
        await bot.process_commands(msg)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```